# Is LuaTeX planned to have as good font capabilities as XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

The title almost says it all. As I understand it, XeTeX was built from the ground up for its font support, while LuaTeX only got `fontspec` support years after its creation. While font support will obviously improve, are there currently any plans to bring the font support in LuaTeX up to the level of what XeTeX is capable of? Or will that be impossible due to the different approach that LuaTeX has to font support?

Comment: Up to now, the only difference of capabilities I know of is that LuaTeX does not support AAT fonts anymore. If there are others, I'll be very interested in learning about them.

Comment: Is the removal of AAT support a major loss for LuaTeX? I don't really know how many font features depend on AAT.

Comment: @fpast Also Graphite is not supported by `luaotfload` (which is the library for font support currently used).

Comment: @Gaussler AAT is available only on Mac OS X.

Comment: On windows and with the scripts/fonts I used I don't see any drawbacks of luatex, actually it is winning over xetex as it can do font expansion. I also don't see anything that xetex can do which couldn't be coded in luatex. The main question is if there is/will be someone who does the work - and this question can't be answered.

Comment: I don't think the question is really answerable in its current form. No one can predict the future, especially the future of open source projects relying on volunteer labour. Furthermore "good" is an overly subjective description. That said, search for "secret plan" here http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/textalk-an-interview-with-khaled-hosny/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess the point is that 'out of the box' LuaTeX _can't_ do any system font use whereas XeTeX can. It's a philosophical difference so there is not much that can be said.

Comment: The above was posted as an answer but considered to be a comment so moved. Not unreasonable of the mods but I think that means the question is too subjective to be answered so I voted to close.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed the question to be more about whether there are *plans* for similar font support.

Comment: @Gaussler see the blog article, the plans are secret:-)

Comment: Nevertheless, isn't it less subjective now? :-)