# Loading system (OTF/TTF) fonts from plain TeX with LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, plain-tex

In XeTeX, I can set up a font pretty straightforwardly with:

```
\font\foo="Minion Pro" at 10pt
```

I don't quite see how to do it. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230736/is-luatex-planned-to-have-as-good-font-capabilities-as-xetex?rq=1) suggests that the answer is "use luaotfload.sty." Is that true or is there something comparable to the above I can do directly in LuaTeX? Or is there some other, better plain-ish TeX way of loading fonts (by which I mean system fonts in TTF or OTF format) from LuaTeX?

Looking at the LuaTeX manual, I see some Lua code. If that's the right way to do it from LuaTeX directly, which functions do I need to use to do this?

Comment: Have you seen/tried the solution at [How to use OpenType fonts with plain-LuaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105869)

Comment: I didn't, so thanks! But both seem to imply the installation of other stuff (ConTeXt or the aforementioned luaotfload.sty); I guess I can survive on one of them but I'm still curious about the "direct" way to do it.

Comment: As explained in egreg's answer, `luaotfload.sty` *is* the "direct" way to do it. `luatex` does not extend `pdftex`'s font handling natively, so the extra Lua code is required.

Comment: Find a copy of `luaotfload.sty` (e.g. on CTAN), copy the contents and paste into your document. Would that count as more 'direct'?

Comment: I take it `luaotfload.sty` is custom Lua code that does the work that XeTeX does, then? I assumed it wrapped some lower level font handling, either Lua primitives or TeX primitives.

Comment: @DanielLyons As already stated, the engine LuaTeX does  _not_ alter the beahviour of the `\font` primitive. You _have_ to use a Lua callback to do this, and you therefore need a font loader mechanism written in Lua. Depending on the font features you wish to support, that is _fat from easy_. If you want to use a plain-like format and load system fonts using a modified `\font` primitive, use XeTeX (which does alter the primitive at the engine level).

Comment: I guess this answers my question as far as it goes here… it does raise interesting questions about what the long-term strategy is for XeTeX and LuaTeX, but this isn't the right forum for that. Thanks for your assistance!